# Hide mouse cursor when mouse cursor interacts with application

Tags: c#, uwp

#### Problem

When the mouse cursor interacts with the application, the mouse cursor should be hidden. The problem is: I don't know how.

#### Question

How can I hide the mouse cursor when the mouse cursor interacts with the application?

Comment: If you show us some code we can try and fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe for to something like [Window.Activated event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window.activated) or similar one to know when user is interacting with the window. And call

```cs
Cursor.Hide();
```

to hide the cursor. Or

```cs
Cursor.Show();
```

to display it

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! :)